# Another GWT module may need to be recompiled

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, pom.xml, mgwt

I'll start with the other threads I've read:

- [GWT module may need to be (re)compiled REDUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719118/gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled-redux)
- [Some subtlety of GWT compilation - "gwt module may need to be (re)compiled."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688067/some-subtlety-of-gwt-compilation-gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled)
- [Google App Engine - recompile GWT module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649349/google-app-engine-recompile-gwt-module)
- [GWT Maven : Module 'xxx' may need to be (re)compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506819/gwt-maven-module-xxx-may-need-to-be-recompiled)

I have taken the following steps to fix this:

1. Cleared my browser cache.
2. Deleted gwt-unitCache folder.
3. Deleted *.nocache.js.
4. Deleted every file that was left over from a previous build. (I did this by looking at the date and time it was created.)
5. Run both maven clean and gwt:clean on my project.
6. Compile by right clicking on the project and going to Google > GWT Compile.
7. Run maven package.
8. Put the war in my JBoss EAP 6.1 (JBoss AS 7) folder.
9. Connect to it and still get the "GWT module may need to be recompiled" error.

What else could be causing this error to come up?

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me in the past when I imported a GWT project to a different computer. Seems you have already done some things I have tried. Before you start, right click on your project, hit Refresh, so you don't miss anything that's not in sync with the file system. There are multiple things it may be, so here's all the things I did to get it working:

Before the following steps also helps if you use the same version of GWT that was originally used to create your project. Also, make sure gwt-servlet.jar, gwt-servlet-deps.jar, validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar, and validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar in your libs directory are the same as the ones from your GWT SDK directory (only if your app uses them).

1. Delete gwt-UnitCache
2. Open up the **war** directory.

   - Delete **ALL** compiled module folders.
   - Delete the war/WEB-INF/**deploy** folder.
   - Delete the war/WEB-INF/classes folder. It may be hidden in Eclipse, so you may have to do it via your file system.
3. Now, on the menus: click **Project** > **Clean...**

   - Make sure a build happens too. Either make "Build automatically" is selected, or use the option in the "Clean" dialog.
4. Do a GWT Compile. If you have more than one module, ONLY compile the main module. Any inherited modules will also be compiled.

I hope this helps. Ask if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Everyone keeps talking about GWT compile. **HOW** do I do GWT compile?

Comment: @TomášZato you can do it with the "GWT Compile Project" button in Eclipse (you must install the GWT SDK first). See step 2 here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/compile.html#compile

Comment: I did every steps, but unfortunately it didn't work.